# (Android) Initial lag in playing sounds - SoundPool and MediaPlayer both

Tags: java, android, multithreading, soundpool

So I've been learning Android dev for a short while now, and I'm writing a metronome app, with tap tempo. What I'm doing is keeping a play button, which starts the metronome when you hit it. In the button's onClick(), I've used a ScheduledExecutorService to repeat the Runnable, which has a SoundPool with the metronome's click loaded.

Here's the thing. The delay between the first two ticks of the metronome is noticeably less than it should be; then it evens out. So if I want it to tap at 120 bpm, it'll speed up to 150 bpm for the first two ticks and then go back to normal. I can only assume the initial tick has been delayed, for some reason.

I've tried using a MediaPlayer instead of a SoundPool, a TimerTask, separate Handlers and Runnables instead of the ScheduledExecutorService, but no luck. What could the problem be?

Comment: Please post the code that initialises the ScheduledExecutorService.